# Alerting user if password doesn't meet requirements before checking on the server

Tags: validation, security, passwords, client-server

If I require a password to have 8 characters and a user tries to enter the password "abc", is there any reason not to immediately respond that the password is invalid instead of sending it to the server to be validated?

If it makes sense to do basic (password requirements) validation on the client side, is there a specific reasons why I should or should not tell them it failed because it didn't match the password requirements (and therefore could never be set as a password)?

Comment: It makes more sense to send it to the server and log every attempt. This way you can lock the account if someone is trying to access it inappropriately​.

Comment: @WalterM - Logging attempts for security reasons can be a good thing, but there is no advantage in logging requests which are rejected anyway, an attacker will hardly execute the javascript anyway. Locking an account because of too many attempts can be misused to lock out a user from the service. The locking should be in place only for a short period, maybe some seconds, to prevent a brute-force attack this is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this is a scenario where user is either changing their password or providing one upon registration - if not, ignore the rest: you should never disclose any unnecessary information upon failed login.

It is perfectly fine to do basic validation on the client side to enhance user experience, as long as you ALSO validate it on the server, since you can never trust anything the client sends you.

It is also a better user experience if you tell them why the password is not ok, instead of frustrating them by not explaining your password limitations and letting them just try to find a suitable password on their own.

Comment: A pedantic note: This doesn't apply to login forms.

Comment: Also, while the server-side checks MUST exist, *if* the client-side code can determine that the server will reject it - there's no reason to send the data. Saves traffic and server resources.